# Dim srt as sort in VBA - compile error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm newbie to vba. I've come across [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/hh360994) good examples that I think I can learn something from. And it's on their excel vba official site, but when I test [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Excel-2010-Sort-Data-196a8f1b) code it gives me compile error: A module is not a valid type. It happens on this line of code:

```
 Dim srt As Sort
```

Am I missing something, or they put incorrect code.

Thank you for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code description explains that the code must be entered into a class module, not a regular module. This is probably the source of the error message. You can insert a class module by choosing the 4th option in the VBE editor's Insert command on the ribbon.

Comment: Thank you. If you can explain what is difference between class module and regular one? When is one used and when another?

Comment: Using classes in a class module makes it possible to take advantage of VBA's object-oriented features: defining new objects, their properties, and the methods that may operate on those objects. There are many explanations and how-to's on class modules that you can find via Google. For example, [**this video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8ceYx_ZLPY) provides a walk-through of classes.